# Rails - nested form won't display in edit template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a form that allows a user to dynamically add nested form fields by clicking either a Text or Url button. Any permutation of Text or Url fields can be added (they can also be removed).

Example - http://imgur.com/4ldNEem

When the form is submitted, the content is displayed in the view template. However, when I go to edit a post at /posts/id/edit, the post content does not appear in the edit template - it's a blank page.

SQL Log https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ueq.png

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :things, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :things
end
```

**Thing Model**

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
end
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "things", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.text     "text"
 t.string   "url"
 t.integer  "post_id"
end
```

**Posts Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def edit
 @post = Post.includes(:things).find(params[:id])
end 

def update
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<button id='addtext'>text</button>
<button id='addurl'>url</button>

<%= form_for @post, url: posts_path, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

 <%= f.fields_for :thing do |ff| %>
 <% end %> 
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<button id='addtext'>text</button>
<button id='addurl'>url</button>

<%= form_for @post, url: posts_path, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

 <%= f.fields_for :thing do |ff| %>
 <% end %> 
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**posts.coffee**

Remove Field

```
jQuery ->
 $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
 $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
 $(this).closest('div').remove()
 event.preventDefault()
```

Add Field (New Template)

```
 current_index = 0

addText = ->
 html = """
  <div>
  <textarea placeholder="Write something..." name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][text]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_text"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][order]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_order" value="#{current_index}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="post[thing_attributes][#{current_index}][_destroy]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}__destroy" value="#current_index" />
  <a class="remove_fields" href="#">x</a>
  </div>
 """

 $("#new_post input[type='submit']").before(html)
 current_index += 1

$ ->
  $('#addtext').on('click', addText)


  current_index = 0

addUrl = ->
 html = """
  <div>
  <input placeholder="http://www..." type="url" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][url]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_url">
  <input type="hidden" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][order]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_order" value="#{current_index}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="post[thing_attributes][#{current_index}][_destroy]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}__destroy" value="#current_index" />
  <a class="remove_fields" href="#">x</a>
   </div>
   """

  $("#new_post input[type='submit']").before(html)
   current_index += 1

$ ->
  $('#addurl').on('click', addUrl)
```

Add Field (Edit Template)

```
     current_index = 0

editText = ->
 html = """
  <div>
  <textarea placeholder="Write something..." name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][text]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_text"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][order]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_order" value="#{current_index}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="post[thing_attributes][#{current_index}][_destroy]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}__destroy" value="#current_index" />
  <a class="remove_fields" href="#">x</a>
  </div>
 """

 $(".edit_post input[type='submit']").before(html)
 current_index += 1

$ ->
  $('#edittext').on('click', editText)


editUrl = ->
 html = """
  <div>
  <input placeholder="http://www..." type="url" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][url]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_url">
  <input type="hidden" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][order]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_order" value="#{current_index}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="post[thing_attributes][#{current_index}][_destroy]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}__destroy" value="#current_index" />
  <a class="remove_fields" href="#">x</a>
  </div>
 """

  $(".edit_post input[type='submit']").before(html)
  current_index += 1

 $ ->
  $('#editurl').on('click', editUrl)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any Java code

Comment: I mean't to press javascript instead - apologies!

Comment: Please do not write this javascript on your own - you are not going to have a good time (there is plenty of things you need to take into account). There is an awesome gem which has been written exactly for that: cocoon https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: @BroiSatse - thank you for commenting! I will utilise the cocoon gem

Comment: my nested_form_fields gem works well for this too: https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
f.fields_for :thing
```

to:

```
f.fields_for :things
```

as it's a has_many association.

Edit: I also just saw that your forms don't have any fields rendered serverside. Adding those fields is required though, for rails to show your created association(s):

```
<%= f.fields_for :things do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.text_field :url %>
  <%= ff.text_area :text %>
<% end %>
```

And as other's suggested: use an existing solution for adding associations via JS. It is tricky. Try out my nested_form_fields gem: https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields

I don't know cocoon, but it seems like a good solution too.

Comment: Great gem Nico! HUGE thank you commenting - perfect!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

#### Let Rails handle your routing

In both `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb`, remove the `url` key from your `form_for` and let Rails figure out the correct route:

```
<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>    
  <%= f.fields_for :thing do |ff| %>
  <% end %> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Even better, put this common code into a partial `_form.html.erb`:

```
# app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>    
  <%= f.fields_for :thing do |ff| %>
  <% end %> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# app/views/posts/new.html.erb | app/views/posts/edit.html.erb
<button id="addtext">Text</button
<button id="addurl">URL</button

<%= render 'form' %>
```

#### Check Logs

The fact you're seeing nothing at all indicates a error. Is there anything else showing in the logs?

```
$ tail -f log/development.log
```

Also be sure to check for any javascript errors (e.g. in Chrome, open the  inspector tools and look for a red cross. If there is one, click it to open up the console and list any errors.

#### Check Indentation

Something I noticed (but it might just be pasting into the SO editor) is that your indentation for line 1 (`current_index = 0`) is out on both the **Add Field (Edit Template)** and **Add Field (New Template)** files. CoffeeScript uses strict indentation rules:

```
#    current_index = 0 # <- Your code has extra indentation here
current_index = 0

editText = ->
  html = """
  <div>
   # ...
```

#### Use Cocoon

Otherwise, as mentioned in the comments above, definitely use the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to save yourself a lot of boilerplate JS/CS. I'd also add [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to the list of super-helpful tools.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback Chris - great advice!